# The best way to "simulate" a bed/mattress

Tags: collision, soft-body

Im new to blender and I want to "simulate" (not sure if I need a simulation for that) how a mattress would behave if you place somthing heavy (e.g. a person) on it. So I want the object I place to kind of sink in, but I guess you all know what I mean. I tried to find a tutorial on that topic but I didnt really find anything so I tried it by myself with soft body simulation but it didnt really work out. Im also not sure if I even need to simulate this or if there is some sort of modifier that can achieve the same effect if it collides with an object. Can anyone help me with this problem? If you know a good tutorial on that topic I would also be very thankful.

Comment: if soft body doesn't work maybe fake physics with shape keys that will deform the object, or take a look at Displace modifier or Lattice, like here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin

Comment: I followed the tutorial about the Vertex weight proximity modifier from the thread u linked. I think this is definetly what Im looking for but now I have a problem with the displacement modifier. Whenever I increase the strength to >0 the mattress starts to increase its scale and it completely messes up the mesh. Is this a common problem and do you know how to fix it? And thanks for your answer, this was a big jump in the right direction for me!

Comment: Hello could you please pack the image you use and share your file (only the mattress), use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51607/make-a-mesh-plane-deform-on-collision-and-stay-deformed/